# How to animate a Geoserver layer in mapbox?

Tags: android, mapbox, geoserver, wms

I'm using Mapbox SDK on my Android app and I want to display a layer coming from my geoserver.

I selected WMS format and works well.

Next step is to animate that layer to show a time-lapse, by providing a time property that ticks every X seconds and update the layer tiles.
WMS supports time property to request a TileSet for a specific time, but I don't know how to set that time in MapBox and update the map TileSet. 
The example is the classic weather application.

If WMS is not the right choice I can choose another format, if is supported by geoserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways that you could animate georeferenced images using the Mapbox Maps SDK for Android. One is to use an [`ImageSource`](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/9.0.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/style/sources/ImageSource.html) (which allows a georeferenced raster image to be shown on the map), and then follow [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/add-an-image-source-with-time-lapse/) to show a time lapse.

To continue using the WMS framework, you could use [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/add-a-wms-source/) to show a WMS source (which it sounds like you have already done successfully). The Mapbox Maps SDK for Android does not have an underlying mechanism for representing updates in time, but you could query your GeoServer and use the results in conjunction with a [`Runnable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable), similar to the `RefreshImageRunnable` in the first example I linked.